# How can I see which modules can be upgraded when upgrading core?

Tags: migrations, 9

Is there a way to get the list of the modules installed on a Drupal 7 site which could be upgraded to Drupal 9 or replaced by modules compatible with Drupal 9?

Answer (score 0):

The module for this is [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status).

However, this will still require additional research-- several modules in Drupal 7 have been partially or completely integrated into core (such as Views, Entity, etc.), and this has resulted in contrib modules getting reworked to handle more use cases than in Drupal 7, so they don't necessarily match `1:1` anymore.